# Can jQuery tell if the <option>s of a <select> element are currently displayed?

Tags: html, jquery, css, select, html-select

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Is there a way to determine if a <select> dropdown menu is open?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709474/is-there-a-way-to-determine-if-a-select-dropdown-menu-is-open)

My customer would like me to display some simple instructions once the user interacts with our `<select>` element in such a way as to cause the `<option>` list to drop down (or "drop up", I suppose, since some browsers open upwards if there is not much room beneath the `<select>` box). And then the instructions should disappear again once the user has either made a new selection and thus caused the option list to disappear, or if they simply close the option list without making a change.

I thought that I was fairly well-experienced with using both CSS/CSS3 selectors and jQuery events to make things like a `<div>` full of instructions appear and disappear, but for this case I am having trouble figuring out whether there is a way to tell when a `<select>` box is not merely “active” or “focused” — both of which can be true while the select box is still closed and not displaying its list of options — but actually open. None of the CSS pseudo-selectors or jQuery events that I have tested let me “see”, much less respond to, the state of the open-ness or closed-ness of the `<select>` box.

Does anyone know how I can set a trigger or write a CSS rule that depends on whether the options list is currently displayed?

Comment: have you tried `onchange`, `onfocus`, `onblur` and `onselect`? none of them worked for you?

Comment: I found this from a little ways back, [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709474/is-there-a-way-to-determine-if-a-select-dropdown-menu-is-open) Might help you out...

Comment: Following the question. It seems interesting

Comment: Thanks, everyone, for finding an earlier version of this question! All of the searches that I had been doing included the word “option” or “options” which happens to not be mentioned at all in the duplicate, so I couldn't find it. I'll leave this question here, closed, in case other people who search later also think of the issue in terms of whether the `<option>` tags are visible or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `$('myID:focus')` is not sufficient, I doubt, that there is another way.

Answer (score 0):

something like

**HTML**

```
<select id="sselect">
    <option value="1st">1st</option>
    <option value="2nd">2nd</option>
    <option value="3rd">3rd</option>
</select>

<br><br>

<div id="ddiv"></div>
```

**JS**

```
$('#sselect')
    .on('keyup', function() { $('#ddiv').show().text($(this).val()) })
    .on('mouseenter', 'option', function() { $('#ddiv').show().text($(this).val()) })
    .on('mouseleave', function() { $('#ddiv').hide() })
```

see it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/RASG/QfMGR/

*tested with FF 15*

Comment: Nice approach, but only works with the mouse action.

Comment: And it only works when the mouse is over the menu, so it doesn't even fully work with the mouse.

Comment: @Manueru_mx: there you go :) keyboard action

Comment: Try checking the key in your keyup handler. The div is showing even when I just tab to the select box.

Comment: @BoltClock♦: ah, got it. tabbing into it showed the div. well, the OP is a very experienced user, im sure he will be able to figure how to not show the div on tab.

Comment: @BoltClock this happens if you have nothing more in the page, for example, add a button or an input and the div hide when you tab. Im using firefox 16

Comment: This does not work for me under Google Chrome. If I bring up your fiddle and press Tab to focus the select box, then your `<div>` appears even though the options are not yet displayed.