# window.addEventLister does not triggering in Some Devices when select tag is in focused state

Tags: javascript, macos, events, addeventlistener

I am trying to do a little custom  arrow animation on select tag with CSS and Javascript.

when user clicks on select tag I am adding `.arrow__up` class to the `parentNode.parentNode` of the select tag. I am removing the `.arrow__up` class if the select tag `parentNode.parentNode` already contains `.arrow__up` class And also when clicking on document.

The major issue I see is in some devices, when the select tag is in focused state if I click anywhere on the page `document.addEventListener('click',function(){})` does not work. I need to remove the class while clicking on window because I need to arrow down  when user click on window after focusing on select tag.

```js
// selectin all select tags
var selectMenuItems =  document.querySelectorAll('.sort select');


selectMenuItems.forEach(curItem => {
  curItem.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
     
    // arrow up 
    if(this.parentNode.parentNode.classList.contains('arrow__up')) {
      this.parentNode.parentNode.classList.remove('arrow__up');
    }
    
    // arrow down if it is already up
    else{
      selectMenuItems.forEach(hasMenuShowItem =>              {hasMenuShowItem.parentNode.parentNode.classList.remove('arrow__up')});
      this.parentNode.parentNode.classList.add('arrow__up');
    }
  });

});

// arrow down when click on window 
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) { // this event is not triggering if any select tag is open on the page
  
  console.log(e.target); 
  
  if(e.target.tagName === 'SELECT') return;   // if user clicks on select tag 
  
  
  selectMenuItems.forEach(hasMenuShowItem => {hasMenuShowItem.parentNode.parentNode.classList.remove('arrow__up')});
});
```

```css
select {
  -moz-appearance: none;
  /* Firefox */
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  /* Safari and Chrome */
  appearance: none;
}

.sort {
  display: inline-block;
}
.sort select {
  width: 140px;
  background: transparent;
  padding: 16px;
}
.sort__arrow {
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  height: 8px;
  width: 8px;
  border: 2px solid #2f2f2f;
  border-top-color: transparent;
  border-right-color: transparent;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-25%) rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-25%) rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-25%) rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: translateY(-25%) rotate(-45deg);
  transform: translateY(-25%) rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}
.sort__year, .sort__month {
  position: relative;
  background: #fff;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.sort__year, .sort__month {
  position: relative;
  background: #fff;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.arrow__up .sort__arrow {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0) rotate(135deg);
  -moz-transform: translateY(0) rotate(135deg);
  -ms-transform: translateY(0) rotate(135deg);
  -o-transform: translateY(0) rotate(135deg);
  transform: translateY(0) rotate(135deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="sort">
  <div class="sort__month ">
    <div class="sort__arrow"></div>
    <label>
      <select class="sort-select">
        <option class="" value="">All</option>
        <option >January</option>
        <option >February</option>
        <option >March</option>
        <option >April</option>
      </select>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="sort">
  <div class="sort__year sort-by">
    <div class="sort__arrow"></div>
    <label>
      <select class="sort-select">
        <option class="" value="">All</option>
        <option >2018</option>
      </select>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

And believe that I am having some issue in Mac OS and other some device and it is working pretty fine on windows.

How to get this working on all devices ?

Comment: Have you tried `document.addEventListener`?

Comment: Yes, I tried but having same issue.

Comment: That is because on OS X Safari, the click event is not fired again if the element has focus. Is there a reason why you are listening on the `click` event instead of something like `focus`, `blur`, `change` or `input`? What do you need to do with the click event that cannot be supplanted by the other input-specific events?

Comment: if you want to do something on click use something like this (not exactly this)  *document.getElementById("myBtnID").addEventListener("click", myFun);*

Comment: Terry,  I  need to do a little arrow  moving animation on select element. For that I need to call function each time when user click on select option and each time when user click on window. And I am having this issue in Mac Os Chrome as well.

Comment: @Vishwa it appears OP is using event delegation which your example will not support

Comment: @Terry,@Vishwa,@Rajesh,@Phil I have edited my question and re-explain my problem.

Comment: @SandeshSapkota This is probably what you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709474/is-there-a-way-to-determine-if-a-select-dropdown-menu-is-open

Comment: @Terry the answer you have suggested describe about mouseenter event on option which is different and 'click' where I am having issue.

Comment: But what you essentially want is to detect whether the select's dropdown is open or not, so you can assign the correct arrow up/down class. It's the same problem.

Comment: @Terry,  the problem I am having is when select tag is  focused if I click anywhere on the page  event like this  on window window.addEventListener('click',function(e){console.log(e));  or any element would not be triggered in some devices.  This is working fine on windows.

Comment: That's a vendor behavior that you cannot circumvent. If you insist on going that route, then there wouldn't be a fix for the OS X behavior.