# How to set aria-expanded to html select

Tags: angular, accessibility, wai-aria

I am trying to implement ADA's aria-expanded on select.

```
    <select department="dep">
     <option *ngFor="let dep of departments" [value]="dep.name">{{dep.name}}</option>
    </select>
```

Basically when user open dropdown i want aria-expanded = true otherwise false.
Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't the correct use of `aria-expanded` so you don't need to do this.

`aria-expanded` is designed to indicate when a collapsible section is open or closed on the control that opens / closes it, for example on a `treeview`.

A `<select>` does not require this as the association is already created by the element.

[Trying to determine if a `<select>` is open is actually quite difficult](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709474/is-there-a-way-to-determine-if-a-select-dropdown-menu-is-open) and results in loads of hacks.

You only need to use `aria-expanded` if you build a custom `<select>` using `<div>`s and `WAI-ARIA` but I would advise against this if you are able to make a `<select>` work for your needs as it is complex and less robust than using a native element. At that point you would need to know whether an item is open or closed anyway to make the custom select work, so toggling would be easy.